# Merge request pipelines + trigger with include:project (another project) does not work

Tags: gitlab-ci

Problem,
I have multiple branches which use a CI config from another branch having nested includes.
It works in all other scenarios except in merge request pipelines.
I have set up the following repository as a demonstration on how to reproduce the error:
https://gitlab.com/UmairShahid/test_CI_1/-/tree/main
any thougts?